# Checking if a variable exist in a List of custom class

Tags: java, android

I have a list of a custom class object I created.

---

```
private List<Grocery> groceryList;
```

where `Grocery` class has `name`, `price` , `quantity` variables and getters...
And I want to check if a grocery product already exist in my list or not,if doesn't exist I want to add it to my list, here is my code:

```
CheckOut hisCheckOut = new CheckOut(itemName ,String.valueOf(price), String.valueOf(orderQuantity), String.valueOf(itemTotalPrice));


    if(!(GroceryActivity.list.contains(itemName))){
        GroceryActivity.list.add(hisCheckOut);
        GroceryActivity.totalItemsPrice += itemTotalPrice;
    }
```

**itemName** is a variable with a normal string name
.This is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because you are checking `itemName` and the item itself.

Do it as follows:

```
boolean found=false;
for(Grocery g: GroceryActivity.list){
    if(g.getItemName().equals(itemName)){
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found){
    //...do whatever you want to do
}
```

Where `itemName` is the name of the item you want to checkout and `getItemName` is the getter of `itemName` in `class Grocery`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Grocery` and the `CheckOut` are entirely different objects and you cannot actually compare two different types of objects using `equals` or `contains`. If you `CheckOut` class holds more items than the `Grocery` object, then I would recommend adding the `Grocery` object itself as an attribute to the `CheckOut` object so that you can use the comparison methods.

Hence the `CheckOut` class may look like as follows.

```
public class CheckOut {
    public long checkOutTime; 
    // ... other extra attributes can go here

    // Add the Grocery object as an attribute
    public Grocery groceryItem; 
}
```

Now when creating the `CheckOut` object, you are basically creating a grocery item in it, and now you can compare with the list of items that you have in your `GroceryActivity`.

```
boolean itemAdded = false;
for (CheckOut checkout : GroceryActivity.list) {
    if (checkout.groceryItem.getName().equals(itemName) {
        // Already added to the checkout
        itemAdded = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!itemAdded) {
    GroceryActivity.list.add(hisCheckOut);
    GroceryActivity.totalItemsPrice += itemTotalPrice;
}
```

I hope that helps!